# Does "Custom Post Type" can have page hierarhy option?

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, pages, hierarchical

I want create "Custom Post Type" that will have next structure:

Post (hierarhy level)-(some-post-id)

> Post 1-1 =>
>
> ```
>       Post 2-2
>       Post 2-3
>       Post 2-4 =>
>                Post 3-5
>                Post 3-6
>                Post 3-7
>       Post 2-8
>       Post 2-9
>       Post 2-10
> ```

I need something like "Page attributes":

http://s019.radikal.ru/i638/1205/19/d533f543c5f7.png

Comment: Post types can be hierarchical - is this a question about url rewriting?

Comment: I want have custom posts type, like standart page, that have hierarhy level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a post type to hierarchical when you register it with [`register_post_type`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type). Simply set the 'hierarchical' argument to *true*.

```
  $args = array(
    'public' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'has_archive' => true, 
    'rewrite' => true,
     ...
    'hierarchical' => true,
     ...
    'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments','page-attributes' )
  ); 
  register_post_type('my-cpt',$args);
```

Comment: Once more, We must add into support, 'page-attributes'

But still no results, because there will be only "order" option.
I want have  hierarhy like by pages, where I will can specify level (parent, grandchild, child and so on).

Comment: Indeed, I'd left out the 'supports' argument.

Comment: But still no results ;)

Comment: In what sense no results? - this works for me (without the '...'s of course.) Does the post type not register, or are you not seeing the page attributes metabox?

Comment: I see
http://s019.radikal.ru/i612/1205/ca/ca78b6f561e7.png

Comment: I want to see http://s019.radikal.ru/i638/1205/19/d533f543c5f7.png

Comment: You need to create a 'my-cpt' first - if no posts of that type exist, then the drop-down menu doesn't appear.